# Error when adding object to NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, swift, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to build a function in my app through which users can add custom specifications to their products. the specifications should be added in an NSMutableArray, but when I want to add an object to it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. here's my code:

```
var specs = NSMutableArray()

func addSpec () {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nieuwe Specificatie", message: "Vul hier een naam voor de nieuwe specificatie in:", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Opslaan", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
                self.specs.addObject(self.newSpecificationTitle.text)
                }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuleren", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
                println("annuleren")
                }))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is your `var specs` property or local variable?

Comment: is `self.newSpecificationTitle` not nil?

Comment: Don't use an `NSMutableArray()`, use an `Array`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing in or where you get your configurationTextField block. But the following code works for me in Xcode 6 DP2

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var newSpecificationTitleTextField: UITextField?
    var specs = NSMutableArray()

    @IBAction func addSpec(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
            self.newSpecificationTitleTextField = textField
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
            self.specs.addObject(self.newSpecificationTitleTextField!.text)
            println("\(self.specs)")
            }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:.Cancel, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
            println("Cancel")
            }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem I have left is that I apparently can not access the newSpecificationTextField!.text, because it returns nil. do you maybe know how to access the textfield in another way to solve this?

Comment: Did you set the `newSpecificationTitleTextField` to the returned textField in the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler callback block?

Comment: you need to something like 
"if let newText = newSpecificationTextField?.text {
    self.specs.addObject(newText)
}"
... this is what Swift is all about - what would it mean to add a nil to an NSMutableArray?

Comment: @DavidArve I have added the code you posted in my app. the initial error is gone, but now it sais that the object I'm trying to add is nil. What should I add to your code to get this error away?

Comment: Got it! the error was the way in which the textfield.text is passed to the array. it should be: `self.specs.addObject(NSString(string: self.newSpecificationTitle.text))`